# Hangman game image javascript only

Tags: javascript

How do I implement these images each time player failed to guess a letter and where should I put it at? When player failed to guess 1 letter, hangman 1 will display, then followed with hangman 2 then hangman 3 and so on? Here is my code. *images is in the console.log*

```
 /* hangman 1
 console.log(" _|_\n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|");

 hangman 2
 console.log("   _____\n  |     |\n  |\n  |\n _|_\n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|\n");

 hangman 3
 console.log("   _____\n  |     |\n  |     o\n  |     | \n _|_    \ \n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|\n");

 hangman 4
 console.log("   _____\n  |     |\n  |     o\n  |    /|\\ \n _|_    \ \n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|\n");

 hangman 5
 console.log("   _____\n  |     |\n  |     o\n  |    /|\\ \n _|_   / \\ \n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|\n");
*/

// Show player their progress | .join returned answer as a string
while (remainingLetters > 0 && lives > 0) {
    (answerArray.join(""));

    guess = readline.question(name + "'s guess (Enter 9 for lifelines or 0 to pass): ");
    guess = guess.toUpperCase();

    //if guess is more than 1 letter or no letter, alert player to guess 1 letter only
    if (guess.length !== 1) {
      console.log("Please enter 1 letter only.");
    }

    //if valid guess
    else {
      if (guesses.includes(guess)) {
        console.log("\nYou have already made this guess, please try another letter!\n");
      } else {
        guesses.push(guess);
        correctGuess = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < Word.length; j++) {
          if (Word[j] == guess) {
            answerArray[j] = guess;
            remainingLetters--;
            correctGuess = 1;
          }
        }

        if (correctGuess == 1) {
          console.log("\nGood job! " + guess + " is one of the letters!\n");
          console.log(JSON.stringify(answerArray) + "\n");
          console.log(JSON.stringify(alphabets) + "\n");
        } else {
          lives -= 1;
          console.log("\nSorry. " + guess + " is not a part of the word.\n");
          console.log(JSON.stringify(answerArray) + "\n");
          console.log(JSON.stringify(alphabets) + "\n");
          console.log("You have " + lives + " lives remaining.\n");
        }
      }
    }

    if (remainingLetters == 0) {
      console.log("Congratulation! You managed to guess the word!\n");
      break;
    }
    
    if (lives == 0) {
      console.log("Game Over... You failed to guess the word. The word is " + Word + ".\n")
    }

  }
```

Comment: `where should I put it at?` you could have some `element` something like `div`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would suggest is storing your various graphics in an array, and storing an index to which is the current graphics - start at zero.

Every time the user gets a wrong answer, you `console.log` the current index and then increment the index:

```
 console.log(graphicsArray[graphicsIndex++]);
```

There is a demo of this below, using a button press to simulate a wrong answer. try it out.

```js
var graphicsArray = [];
graphicsArray.push(" _|_\n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|");
graphicsArray.push("   _____\n  |     |\n  |\n  |\n _|_\n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|\n");
graphicsArray.push("   _____\n  |     |\n  |     o\n  |     | \n _|_    \ \n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|\n");
graphicsArray.push("   _____\n  |     |\n  |     o\n  |    /|\\ \n _|_    \ \n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|\n");
graphicsArray.push("   _____\n  |     |\n  |     o\n  |    /|\\ \n _|_   / \\ \n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|\n");


var graphicsIndex = 0;

document.querySelector("#demo").onclick = () => {
    console.log(graphicsArray[graphicsIndex++]);
}
```

```html
<button id="demo">press me</button>
```

You would do this in the part of your code which decrements the number of lives.

```
// ... //
if (correctGuess == 1) {
   console.log("\nGood job! " + guess + " is one of the letters!\n");
   console.log(JSON.stringify(answerArray) + "\n");
   console.log(JSON.stringify(alphabets) + "\n");
} else {
   lives -= 1;
   console.log("\nSorry. " + guess + " is not a part of the word.\n");
   console.log(JSON.stringify(answerArray) + "\n");
   console.log(JSON.stringify(alphabets) + "\n");
   console.log("You have " + lives + " lives remaining.\n");
   console.log(graphicsArray[graphicsIndex++]);
}
// ... //
```

Comment: I am using javascript only, there won't be html included.

Comment: @Heheh  _know_ that. I was just demonstrating using html. Read the last line of this answer. I have made the answer _even clearer_

Comment: yep it works! Thank you so much! Sorry, didn't see your answer at the last line before commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Generator !
To better understand what a generator is you can go here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

```js
/* This function generates your images */
function* hangmanGenerator() {
    yield console.log(" _|_\n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|");
    yield console.log("   _____\n  |     |\n  |\n  |\n _|_\n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|\n");
    yield console.log("   _____\n  |     |\n  |     o\n  |     | \n _|_    \ \n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|\n");
    yield console.log("   _____\n  |     |\n  |     o\n  |    /|\\ \n _|_    \ \n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|\n");
    yield console.log("   _____\n  |     |\n  |     o\n  |    /|\\ \n _|_   / \\ \n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|\n");
}

/* This is the istance of your image generator */
const generator = hangmanGenerator();

/* This is how you get the images out of your generator */
generator.next().value  /* Hangman 1*/
generator.next().value  /* Hangman 2*/
generator.next().value  /* Hangman 3*/
generator.next().value  /* Hangman 4*/
generator.next().value  /* Hangman 5*/
generator.next().value  /* No value because you're out of yields -> game over */
```

Your code should look like this:

```js
//Your code...
//The function definition can go wherever you want in your code as long as it's before the while loop
function* hangmanGenerator() {
    yield console.log(" _|_\n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|");
    yield console.log("   _____\n  |     |\n  |\n  |\n _|_\n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|\n");
    yield console.log("   _____\n  |     |\n  |     o\n  |     | \n _|_    \ \n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|\n");
    yield console.log("   _____\n  |     |\n  |     o\n  |    /|\\ \n _|_    \ \n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|\n");
    yield console.log("   _____\n  |     |\n  |     o\n  |    /|\\ \n _|_   / \\ \n|   |_____\n|         |\n|_________|\n");
}
//As the generator definition you can istanciate the generator object wherever you need 
//as long as it's visible in the while loop
const generator = hangmanGenerator();

// Show player their progress | .join returned answer as a string
while (remainingLetters > 0 && lives > 0) {
    (answerArray.join(""));

    guess = readline.question(name + "'s guess (Enter 9 for lifelines or 0 to pass): ");
    guess = guess.toUpperCase();

    //if guess is more than 1 letter or no letter, alert player to guess 1 letter only
    if (guess.length !== 1) {
      console.log("Please enter 1 letter only.");
    }

    //if valid guess
    else {
      if (guesses.includes(guess)) {
        console.log("\nYou have already made this guess, please try another letter!\n");
      } else {
        guesses.push(guess);
        correctGuess = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < Word.length; j++) {
          if (Word[j] == guess) {
            answerArray[j] = guess;
            remainingLetters--;
            correctGuess = 1;
          }
        }

        if (correctGuess == 1) {
          console.log("\nGood job! " + guess + " is one of the letters!\n");
          console.log(JSON.stringify(answerArray) + "\n");
          console.log(JSON.stringify(alphabets) + "\n");
        } else {
          lives -= 1;
          console.log("\nSorry. " + guess + " is not a part of the word.\n");
          console.log(JSON.stringify(answerArray) + "\n");
          console.log(JSON.stringify(alphabets) + "\n");
          console.log("You have " + lives + " lives remaining.\n");
          //HERE you show the hangman in the console
          generator.next().value;
        }
      }
    }

    if (remainingLetters == 0) {
      console.log("Congratulation! You managed to guess the word!\n");
      break;
    }
    
    if (lives == 0) {
      console.log("Game Over... You failed to guess the word. The word is " + Word + ".\n")
    }

  }
```

Comment: Not really useful, as it adds little value and is incompatible with older browsers (especially IE).

Comment: What do you mean with "adds little value" ? For the compatibility only IE and opera mini are not supporting generators (specific compatibility wasn't a question requirement anyway): https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-generators

Comment: The proposed solution with a generator has no apparent advantage over a simple array, as proposed by Jamiec, but some disadvantages. There are good uses cases for generators, this isn't one.

Comment: Well...using a generator would allow to have a simpler sintax, forget about any one-usecase-only array index and out-of-bounds checks, but i understand that there are way more interesting scenarios in which generators may be a lot more helpful.
Thank you for the comment anyway ! Have a good day !